# ErrorHandling php

Tags: php, error-handling

I wrote an error handler to handle different kind of errors in php(even parse errors etc.).

Question:

As I now can detect an errortype(the constant) it is necessary to identify which errors I should allow or not and in which case do a gentle shutdown.
If I look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php I see all the different constants for different kind of errors.

The question is:

1)Is there some kind of relation between these constants for error handling. Lets say above a level I know that I dont want to print the error on my screen etc? Or do I have to set this manually for every error-constant(seems like it)?

2) How to provoke every error on the screen example without using trigger_error() or user_error()? Is there some kind of list to produce those errors and which ones I can produce with code?

Cheers and thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "above a level I know"? The levels are usually notice < warning < error.

Comment: I think by "above a level" he's asking if the numeric value of the constant can be used to identify relative criticality of an error.  The answer is "no".

Comment: @talentfrei - The errors you can raise in code are E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_DEPRECATED, E_NOTICE

Comment: @jack If I look the link I posted there are a lot more errors than you wrote down. But what Im looking for is some kind of leveling with the error type.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Allright. Do you also know if there is some kind of list to produce errors? So I can identify these errors without producing everyone on my own? Or which kind of errors can I produce with code(this was implicit in my second question).

Comment: @StevenMoseley ...thats not entirely true. I can also produce a parse error i.e.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Forgot that one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group all the notice, warning and error constants together like this:

```
notice : 8 + 1024 + 2048 + 8192 + 16384 = 27656 0x6c08
warning: 2 + 32 + 128 + 512             = 674   0x2a2
error  : 1 + 16 + 64 + 256 + 4096       = 4433  0x1151
```

*You could also add them by explicitly using the constant names, e.g. `E_ERROR`, etc.*

So:

```
$is_notice  = $code & 0x6c08 != 0;
$is_warning = $code & 0x2a2 != 0;
$is_error = $code & 0x1151 != 0;
```

As for your second question, are you looking for code that would trigger the above distinct levels?

```
$f = fopen($a, 'r'); // notice + warning
$f->read(); // error

include 'script_with_parse_error.php'; // e_parse

function test(Iterator $i) { }
test(123); // e_recoverable_error

function modify(&$i) { ++$i; }
modify(123); // e_strict

$x = split(',', ''); // e_deprecated
```

The `E_USER` events can only be generated with `trigger_error()` of course.

Comment: yes exacly...second question is how to trigger all possible errors(and which one I can trigger).

Comment: @jack...thx a lot. One last question. All the other error you havent listed here are not produceable directly, right? Or do I miss sth (not meaing E_USER)

Comment: You could use `mysql_escape_string` to throw an E_DEPRECATED

Comment: @talentfrei I'm not sure how one would be able to produce `E_CORE_` errors ... or whether you can even handle them, like failing to load a particular module perhaps.

Comment: @jack Yeah...just realized that that these are the only questionmarks in my list. But for my leveling it is definitive a fatal one, of course.

Comment: @talentfrei Yes, assuming you are even able to handle them :)